# Show the JSON data in the new HTML tab using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I develop a Bitcoin wallet app with the landing page,

[image]

When I click the `Balance` button, I get the `JSON` in the console, 
[image]

The respective code to show `JSON` was,

```
   $("#balance").click(function () {
            clearInterval(transactionsIntervalId);
            clearInterval(balanceIntervalId);

            balanceIntervalId = setInterval(function () {

                var address = $('#address').find(":selected").text();
                var explorers = require('bitcore-explorers');
                var client = new explorers.Insight('testnet');

                client.address(address, function (err, info) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    info.wallet = info.address.toString();
                    setConsoleData('info:', info);
                });
            }, 1000);

        });
```

I have to change it into,

```
$("#balance").click(function () {

            clearInterval(transactionsIntervalId);
            clearInterval(balanceIntervalId);

            var address = $('#address').find(":selected").text();
            var explorers = require('bitcore-explorers');
            var client = new explorers.Insight('testnet');

            window.open('balance.html#' + address);
        });
```

So, it's basically open `balance.html` page in the new tab. The `balance.html` is provided below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>Balance</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Theme CSS -->
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>


    <!-- to clear the saved address use: localStorage.clear(); -->
    <body id="page-top" class="index">

    The current balance 
    </body>

</html>
```

There are `balance` and the `wallet` info in the `JSON` provided earlier and I would like to show them in the `balance.html` page.  How to do that? I can provide more info if required.

Comment: How to do that? Do what?

Comment: parse the json? and then do a loop into table?

Comment: Parse the JSON. the balance value can be accessed with "info.balance"

Comment: How to send the data to the `balance.html` page? An answer with the code will be helpful .

Comment: why don't oinly on balance page load fire to get the JSON instead of on button click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $("#balance").click(function () {
    clearInterval(transactionsIntervalId);
    clearInterval(balanceIntervalId);

    balanceIntervalId = setInterval(function () {

        var address = $('#address').find(":selected").text();
        var explorers = require('bitcore-explorers');
        var client = new explorers.Insight('testnet');

        client.address(address, function (err, info) {
            if (err) throw err;
            info.wallet = info.address.toString();
            window.open('balance.html?balance ='+ info.balance +'&wallet ='+ info.wallet);  
        });
    }, 1000);

});
```

balance.html

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Balance</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>


<!-- to clear the saved address use: localStorage.clear(); -->
<body id="page-top" class="index">

<div id="balance"></div>
<div id="wallet"></div>
</body>
```

```
<script> 
        function getQueryString(name) { 
            var reg = new RegExp("(^|&)" + name + "=([^&]*)(&|$)", "i"); 
            var r = window.location.search.substr(1).match(reg); 
            if (r != null) 
                return unescape(r[2]); 
            return null; 
        }
        balance = getQueryString('balance'); 
        wallet = getQueryString('wallet'); 

        document.getElementById('balance').innerHTML = balance;
        document.getElementById('wallet').innerHTML = wallet;
    </script>
```

Comment: The code looks OK, but, it's not working. It's not proving any errors in the console as well. How should I approach the issue?

Comment: What's the new page url like? Does it contain parameters?

Comment: The new page doesn't open. Give me few seconds and I will provide you
the link of the repo. HERE IS THE REPO <https://github.com/Chaklader/Bitcoin-Wallet-JS.git>

Comment: You can console.log(info) ,See if he can print properly

Comment: I can print the `balance` and the `wallet` in the console. May be the reason is we can't have the `window.open` inside the function?

Comment: If you can run to print info and not open a new page, the console will display errors

Comment: The code keeps opening new `balance.html` pages in every 1 sec and it was the reason `Chrome' blocked it. How do I change it to open the new tab only when I clicked the button?

Comment: Delete setInterval

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to transfer the data from the current page to the new open page and display it?

Comment: Is this a answer or comment?

Comment: Yes, how about writing that in the answer? I assume it would require to pass the `info.balance` and `info.wallet` to the `balance.html` page.

Comment: You can use the URL parameter to pass values to the new page, and then use the JS to parse the URL parameter and display on the new page

Comment: It will be helpful to write the recommendation with implementation code as an answer.

Comment: this page: window.open('balance.html?balance=' + balance+'&wallet='+wallet);
balance.html:
<script>
function getQueryString(name) { 
var reg = new RegExp("(^|&)" + name + "=([^&]*)(&|$)", "i"); 
var r = window.location.search.substr(1).match(reg); 
if (r != null) return unescape(r[2]); return null; 
}

balance = getQueryString('balance');
wallet = getQueryString('wallet');


 </script>

Comment: You may write it as an answer and I will accept it then.